# Javascript: Set date, show date +14 days. Update date again after 14 days

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to write some javascript that tracks an event that occurs every 14 days, so I want to display a NextEvent date and a LastEvent date.

Once the current date == NextEvent date, then that date would become the LastEvent date, and the new NextEvent date would become the current date + 14 days.

I've got this so far, but I don't know how I'd go about updating the dates after 14 days has passed. Only really know HTML, but trying to self-learn more. This has stumped me though.

Any help appreciated!

```
<script>
var last = new Date();
last.setFullYear(2020, 07, 14);

document.write(""+last);
</script>

<script>
var next = last;
next.setDate(next.getDate() + 14);

document.write(""+next);
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information to help people answer this? What is a "wipe" and where does this operation occur? Are you getting the "last wipe" date from a web service, for example, or is this purely client-side (in the browser)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. You are searching for a way that updates the date after 14 days? You could use the **`localStorage`** and save the date.

Now if you load the site, you would load the date from the `localStorage` and compare it to the current date to check if 14 days has passed. If it has, just overwrite the value in `localStorage` to update it. Otherwise is there no value, you would just write the value in the `localStorage`.

Here is a reference, how to use the **`localStorage`**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hi Justin. Hadn't heard of that, but looked it up and it seems to be the right thing. I am trying to mimic what they did on this site: https://www.pixierust.co.uk/ 

Their dates are a week apart instead of the 14 days I'd like, and when current date would equal the date under "Next Wipe" then the dates would update.

If you still think its LocalStorage then I'll try fiddle around with it :D

Comment: Yeah i think the localStorage is perfect for you to test this feature. After a page reload, the data still exists. If you want to be go more advanced, then you should setup a backend with an easy database like MongoDB